# Finding a positive definite function to apply Lyapunov's Stability Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Prove that the zero solution of the equation $$\ddot{x} +
>  (1-x^2)\dot{x} + x=0$$ is stable by using Lyapunov's Stability
>   Theorem.

An indeed straight forward question but in general hard to tackle!

Let $\dot{x}=y$. The we have the system $$\dot{x}=y$$ $$\dot{y}=(x^2-1)y-x$$
It remains to find a positive definite function $V$ to complete the proof. However, I fail to do so. The book suggests $V=x^2 + y^2$ but it leads me to nowhere. Can anyone give me some tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would linearize it, but that doesn't use the method you're looking for. Let me know if you want that method as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the the equation $$\ddot{x}+ (1-x^2)\dot{x} + x=0$$ is stable by using Lyapunov's Stability Theorem

Let $\dot{x}=y$. The we have the system $$\dot{x}=y$$ $$\dot{y}=-(1-x^2)y-x$$

Let $V=x^2 + y^2$.

Then $$\dot{V}=2x\dot{x} + 2y\dot{y}=2xy+2y[-(1-x^2)y-x]=-2(1-x^2)y^2$$

In the neighborhood of the equilibrium $(0,0)$ we have $-2(1-x^2)y^2<0$, therefore the equilibrium $(0, 0)$ is asymptotically stable.

Comment: what if i choose (3,1)? then $\dot{V}(3,1)>0$

Comment: $(3,1)$ is not an equilibrium point, if it were it would be unstable.

Comment: ok. so i review my notes and i need to define $V$ 'on some open ball $B$'. lets take $B$ to be the open unit ball. it still contain points like $(0.5, 0)$ where $\dot{V}(0.5, 0)=0$, so should we conclude that the solution is stable but not asymptotically stable?

Comment: thx for your reply!:)